# How to get a smooth bitmap scrolling in a window?

Tags: c++, delphi, windows-7, directx, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to scroll bitmap smoothly in a window. Bitmap data is generated dynamically. Actual drawing (including `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw`, but not `Present`) takes about 2 ms. Bitmap data shifted (scrolled) with constant value each turn of the drawing loop. Most of time scrolling is ok, but when I maximize application window (and window with bitmap) scrolling begin stuttering (SwapChain buffers are resized and RenderTarget recreated after window resizing).

Changing `BufferCount` value or `SwapEffect` to `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL` has no effect.

What can I do to get rid of this stuttering? What I'm doing wrong?

Full source code of test app you can find at https://github.com/code-kot/VisualizerTest6

Here is **only fragments** from my code:

```
FDXGISwapChain: IDXGISwapChain;

// creating swapchain
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format := DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count := 1;
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality := 0;
SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage := DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
SwapChainDesc.BufferCount := 4;
SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow := Self.Handle;
SwapChainDesc.Windowed := True;
SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect := DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

FDXGIFactory.CreateSwapChain(FD3D10Device, SwapChainDesc, FDXGISwapChain);

// creating render target
FDXGISwapChain.GetBuffer(0, IDXGISurface, DXGISurface);

RenderTargetProperties := D2D1RenderTargetProperties(
  D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE,
  D2D1PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
  DpiX, DpiY);

D2DFactory.CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(
  DXGISurface,
  RenderTargetProperties,
  FRenderTarget);

// drawing
FRenderTarget.BeginDraw;
  // ... drawing my bitmap
FRenderTarget.EndDraw;

FDXGISwapChain.Present(1, 0);
```

---

**UPD**

Starting app maximized has no effect. Yes, I handling lost device condition, but it never happens. Recreating all resources after resize has no effect.

Answers with C++ examples are also acceptable.

Comment: I believe you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Also version info.

Comment: Does it stutter if application was started maximized? Do you handling lost device condition? Try to free and create from scratch all surfaces and other resources on window resize.